"Lell" is the units coming upon the bar plot , what does it mean? If it represents units, how to change the units?
image
What does 'LELL' on the top-left on the graph pic attached represents??
How to change units on the y-axis?
Along the y-axis, how should i change the units if i want to?
How to change the numbers on y-axis to a scaled value?
For example : Representing the values on the y-axis in million scale or billion scale ..etc.
I am using direct math to divide the value so that my graph looks good.
But it is too naive.
Is there an in-built function that can change the units accordingly?

It says "one times ten to the power of eleven" (100 billion, in other words). The characters are "1" (number one) not "l" (lower-case character L). A good reason for using a serif font. If you want to change units ... multiply your data by the appropriate scale factor!

Thank you , but Is there a no way other than directly scaling the value?

What's so difficult about multiplying by a scale factor?

Sorry but If I have a 100 languages streaming, then do i have to multiply each one of them individually with a scale value?

If you want to compare like with like then you obviously have to multiply all pieces of data by the same multiplier.

Okay. Thank you so much.

Are you sure your y-axis label is correct? I see you have some x/y variables divided by 1 billion, but those variables appear to be different from what you're plotting. Your plot currently shows 120 quintillion hours for English. That seems high...

Yeah that x/y variables have nothing to do with that , sorry my bad not to remove them from the pic
